# Is this program correct?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, return-value

Can someone tell me, if function fun() is correct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *fun(int *, int *, int, int);
int main(void) {
int v1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int v2[] = {6,7,8,9,10};
    int v1Size = sizeof(v1)/sizeof(v1[0]);
    int v2Size = sizeof(v2)/sizeof(v2[0]);
    int *v = fun(v1, v2, v1Size, v2Size);
    if(v == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v1Size; ++i)
        printf("%d ", v[i]);

}

int *fun(int *v1, int *v2, int v1Size, int v2Size){
    if(v1Size!=v2Size)
        return NULL;
    const int size = v1Size;
    int v[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        v[i]=v1[i]+v2[i];

    int *p = v;
    return p;
}
```

For me, it returns the pointer that points memory that will be freed after leaving the fuction body. But valgrind doesn't show any error and it works just fine.

Comment: isn't valgrind suppose to check for dynamic memory issues?

Comment: The call, in main(), to printf() is already overlaying some of the stack used by the array `v[]` in function: `fun()`.  Therefore, IF the values being printed are correct, it is only due to blind luck.  suggest adding more parameters to the call to `printf()` so more of the stack is modified then you should clearly see the result of the undefined behaviour.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then the compiler would have output a warning: `comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions`  for this line: `for(size_t i = 0; i < v1Size; ++i)`.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`   I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: when I run the posted code on my computer (x64 with linux 14.04) this is the output: `7 9 -1099664112 32638 0 `  which is definitely not correct.   The incorrect values are due to the undefined behaviour resulting from returning a pointer to an array that is on the stack of the called function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *works just fine*

Stop !! it's one of the possible outcome of invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As you correctly mentioned, the returned pointer won't be valid (*VLAs reside in auto scope (stack), in general, as in `gcc`*) after returning from `fun()`. Using the return value will lead to UB.

Answer (score 3):

Returning the address of a local variable is not "fine".  Once the function exits, `v` no longer exists, so any pointer to it is no longer valid.  Obviously, the storage that `v` occupied still exists, and as long as nothing else overwrites that storage, your code will *appear* to function correctly.

Note the emphasis on *appear*.  Your code could just as easily crash, or give garbled output, or otherwise be put into a bad state.  It depends on how you use that returned pointer value.

`v` has `auto` storage duration, meaning storage for it is allocated at function entry and released at function exit.  Valgrind isn't going to say boo about it, because it's not the kind of thing Valgrind checks.